# module compiled against API version

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intenté ejecutar [un proyecto de python](https://github.com/NathalieFouet/Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation) con Rasa, pero inesperadamente tuve dos errores que me desconcertaron: algunos `failed to import` mensaje porque `module compiled against API vesion` y otro `Python has stopped working`. Es la primera vez que estoy codificando con Windows. ¿Hice algo mal?

```
(cha_env36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation>python run_app.py
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2018-11-26 19:35:40.214152: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

[image]

#### Actualizacion

Parece que funciona el upgrade de numpy. Sin embargo hay un module que falta : `No module named 'rasa_core.channels.rest'`

```
(cha_env36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation>pip install numpy --upgrade
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/70/7096a735b27359dbc0c380b23b9c9bd05fea62233f95849c43a6b02c5f40/numpy-1.15.4-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (13.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.5MB 207kB/s
rasa-nlu 0.13.8 has requirement matplotlib~=2.0, but you'll have matplotlib 1.5.3 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement coloredlogs~=10.0, but you'll have coloredlogs 7.3 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement ConfigArgParse~=0.13.0, but you'll have configargparse 0.12.0 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement fakeredis~=0.10.0, but you'll have fakeredis 0.8.2 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement fbmessenger~=5.0, but you'll have fbmessenger 4.3.1 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement flask~=1.0, but you'll have flask 0.12 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement networkx~=2.0, but you'll have networkx 1.11 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement packaging~=17.0, but you'll have packaging 18.0 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement requests~=2.20, but you'll have requests 2.14.2 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement tensorflow==1.10.0, but you'll have tensorflow 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.13.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.13.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.13.1
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
(cha_env36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation>python run_app.py
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation\cha_env36\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rasa_slack_connector import SlackInput
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation\rasa_slack_connector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rasa_core.channels.rest import HttpInputComponent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_core.channels.rest'
```

Pero pienso que no esta relacionada.

Comment: Tienes al menos dos versiones de numpy instaladas. Prueba `pip install numpy --upgrade` si funciona genial, si no puede ser más complicado... Ya que dices que es la primera vez con Windows, asumo que acabas de empezar y que no sería mayor problema reinstalar. Yo borraría todo lo que tienes de python/numpy/ etc y usaría [`anaconda`](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) para volver a instalarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia Pienso que el problema esta solucionado está solucionado aunque tengo anotro que aparecia. Puesto la repuesta del terminal aqui para ser seguro si quiere verlo. Voy a preguntar sobre el forum de Rasa el problema con `rasa_core.channels.rest`